# htaccess deny acces to all php files but redirect old non-existing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403

As far as I know, the `L` flag is only applicable to `mod_rewrite` and `S` to rewrite rules. However, I have some old indexed php pages, which I want to redirect to new URL. I have like zillion of lines like this:

```
RewriteRule ^example.php(/?.*) /example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This would normaly work, but I have also this code in my .htaccess:

```
<Files *.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>
```

I am wondering, if it is possible to skip this if the rule is met, as long as these two flags mentioned above do not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep all specific redirect rules at the top followed by a generic rule to deny access to `.php` files as below:

```
RewriteEngine On

# specific .php handlers
RewriteRule ^example\.php(/.*)?$ /example/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# generic rule to deny .php files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F,NC]
```